# Google earth plug in loading old ground overlay

Tags: kml, google-earth

Im having a problem were i have updated Groundoverlay images and the links, but the plug in is either showing the old overlays or just greyed out, when viewed on my PC

I know the coding is ok as is i view it on my laptop everything is correct so is it a problem with the plug in cacheing old data or do i need to make use of the fetchkml code?